# Video upload HTML5 is not uploading on my page as expected

Tags: html

Hello everyone could anyone tell me why the video below is not uploading on my page?

```
<body>
    <p>Natural Mystic music video</p>
      <iframe width="420" height="315"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkndVzfOeRc">
      </iframe> 
</body>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What web browser are you using?

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to me. I'm using firefox

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the embed form(which you can find pressing share on the youtube video), or youtube will refuse the connection.

```html
<body>
  <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VkndVzfOeRc">
</iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Tiberius, I tried that but it was not working. You can try to run it with snippet and see.

Comment: Try it for real I think snippets doesn't load iframes.

Comment: Stackoverflow only allows iframes of the same domain, as hinted by the error message in the JS console. But the code should work when ran in a proper environment.

Comment: here is the embed for from youtube: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VkndVzfOeRc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

For those who have similar problem in the future, please DO NOT USE THE iframe tag, instead, use the format below as it works now:

```
    <object width="420" height="315"
        data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VkndVzfOeRc">
    </object>
```

Thank you to all of you who tried to help.

Comment: It's a firefox issue. I dealt with a similar problem earlier. You should be aware that <object> will not appear for those using the NoScript plugin